# Silverstripe: Front-end User Upload Directory

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm trying to create a module that allows users to upload files from the front end. I've seen this asked before but not specifically what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically, I have a 'user dashboard' on the front end.

On that dashboard I'd like a "My files" area that the user can see a list of all the files they've uploaded.

I'm thinking of adding an "Upload file" button which allows the user to obviously upload their file...

This file then gets saved in to the back end of silverstripe in a separate folder (I would imagine, separated by User ID/Name).

I'm not really sure where to start as I'm quite new to back-end development. How would I go about creating this functionality? Would I create a module that somehow extends the upload/files section of the CMS. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should really just try it out yourself. StackOverflow is here to help you when you get stuck on a problem, not to help you get started on a new project. Just take a look at the [UploadField](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/) documentation. You probably want to use `setCanPreviewFolder`, `setCanAttachExisting` and `setAllowedExtension`. Maybe you should also take a look at securing your assets. When you get in trouble coding all this, create a new question with as much info as possible and you will probably get a better answer.

Comment: Was the first two sentences necessary? You have essentially answered my question, and given me the direction I requested in the first place with the rest of the answer. How can I try it myself if I don't know where to start?

Comment: It was just a helpfull tip, as these kind of questions can get flagged as being too 'broad'. You indicated I answered your question so I made a 'real' answer out of it. Now you can accept that answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a look at the [UploadField](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/) documentation. You probably want to use `setCanPreviewFolder`, `setCanAttachExisting` and `setAllowedExtension`. Maybe you should also take a look at [securing your assets](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-secureassets). When you get in trouble coding all this, create a new question with as much info as possible and you will probably get a better answer.